# Weapon used to punish sleeping mikdash guards

Tags: rambam, beis-hamikdash, reward-punishment, tractate-shekalim, masechet-midot

The very start of *mishnayos maseches Midos* mentions that the *l'viyim* guarded the *bes hamikdash* in various locations, and that, if the captain of the guards caught a guard asleep on the job, he'd hit him with a stick. The *Rambam*'s commentary to the start of chapter 5 of *mishnayos maseches Sh'kalim* says that this punishment was carried out with a strap. How do we explain the contradiction between the *mishnayos*, or why or on what basis does the *Rambam* explain *Sh'kalim* as applying to the sleeping-guard case, which *Midos* clearly says featured use of a stick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't possibly be referring to the *supervisor*'s a walking stick, as you may not bring a walking stick into the Har haBayit, as we learn in Brachot ([Mishna 9:5](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00911.html#HtmpReportNum0056_L2)):

> לֹא יִכָּנֵס לְהַר הַבַּיִת בְּמַקְלוֹ

Add a third Mishna and you have a solution.

Makos [Ch. 3:12-13](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01310.html#HtmpReportNum0029_L2) describes that when giving Malkus (the 39 lashes), the instrument used had a handle 1 Tefach long, from which straps were attached.

So we can reconcile your 2 Mishnayos and say that the person in charge of the Levi'im had a **stick with straps attached** - like Bet Din used.

[Midos 1:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01347.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2): **He hit him with his stick**, to which straps were attached.

or

[Shekalim 5:1](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01088.html#HtmpReportNum0025_L2) **He whipped him with the straps**, connected to his stick.

The above can be proven by the words of the  [כסף משנה in הלכות כלי המקדש והעובדים בו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2)  who says that the instrument used was the same they used for Malkus:

> **שלוקה מן הממונה בפקיע**. אמינא מאי פקיע? נגדא! ופירש''י נגדא: רצועות מלקות

Actually it's a Gemara in  [Yoma 23a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00882.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2) that says:

> ולא עוד אלא שלוקה מן הממונה בפקיע אמינא מאי פקיע נגדא

To which Rashi comments: **נגדא**. רצועות מלקות.

For that matter, if you look in the Rambam in [הלכות כלי המקדש והעובדים בו - פרק שביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2) he says:

> **ד:** זֶה שֶׁעַל הַשּׁוֹמְרִים הוּא אִישׁ הַר הַבַּיִת שֶׁמְּסַבֵּב עַל הַלְוִיִּם בְּכָל לַיְלָה וְכָל מִי שֶׁיָּשֵׁן עַל מִשְׁמָרוֹ מַלְקֶה אוֹתוֹ בְּמַקְלוֹ וְשׂוֹרֵף אֶת כְּסוּתוֹ: ‏

So the Rambam himself says it's a strap (in Pirush MaMishnayos) and a stick (in the Yad).